# Does iPhone SDK support links in PDF and can they be routed internally?

Tags: iphone, pdf, ipad

I am producing a magazine for a client for the iPad and they would to include PDF pages with internal links to videos/other pages etc.

Can this be done with the standard PDF controls etc?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably need to do such a thing with a  UIWebview.

Yep, sure enough. After searching around on Google I found this - [PDF Viewer Tutorial](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/16552-pdf-viewer-tutorial.html)

And, note, if you are including a PDF file as a resource file you could this:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfFileName" ofType:@".pdf"];
NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL URLWithString:pdfPath];
```

Comment: Ah this looks about write I'll test and post confirmation